# Why are Craigslist posts full of question marks?

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts, unicode

There's no craigslist presence in my city, but sometimes I browse the ["best of"](http://www.craigslist.org/about/best/all/) because it's funny or interesting.

Why are some posts full of question marks?  It looks like all punctuation except commas and full stops is being replaced by � symbols.

[image: Example]

Firefox 3 on Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here's an example of that](http://www.craigslist.org/about/best/fay/1270864495.html) from Craigslist.

That page is encoded using ISO-8859-1 encoding, however, the web server is announcing that the page is in UTF-8 by sending down the following header:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

This is a bug in Craigslist. It is a fair assumption that the Craigslist programmers do not know [the absolute minimum that working programmers should know](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) about Unicode.

Those curly apostrophes, in ISO-8859-1, are encoded using bytes which, in UTF-8, would not be valid. Thus they appear as `<?>` in Firefox and squares in IE.

To fix the problem when you are viewing the page, go up to the View menu and choose Character Encoding > Western (ISO-8859-1) to tell the browser what encoding the page is really in.

Comment: We'll have to start calling you Kibo.

Comment: That page is actually encoded in windows-1252.  ISO 8859-1 does not even have curly quotes.  However when you choose ISO-8859-1 in Firefox, bytes in the 80-9F range (not defined by ISO-8859-1) display as the corresponding windows-1252 graphic.

Comment: thank you, oh microsoft, for giving us curly quotes that mess up our cut-n-pastes, for inconsistent codepages, for... oh, i give up.

Answer (score 19):

Often that happens when you cut and paste from a program that's using its own code page or character set.  The local program sees them as apostrophes, but since it's a non-standard character it has no meaning for the renderer so it just defaults to the black diamond/white question mark �.

Obligatory Joelonsoftware photo:

[image]

More on unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html